# How to set circuitikz node label position in \draw mode

Tags: nodes, circuitikz

I'm having trouble when trying to position a label of a circuit element in `\draw` mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[american, siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} \draw
(0,0) node[ocirc]{Anode} to[short,i=$i'_D$] (1,0) to[empty diode, v=$v'_D$] 
(3,0) node[ocirc]{Cathode};
%\node at (0,0) [left] {Anode};
%\node at (3,0) [right] {Cathode};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption*{Figure: Diode}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The only alternative I can think of is placing and labeling individual nodes (commented) but I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way. I tried `node[ocirc, left]` but that wouldn't compile & I'm unsure why, is it because nodes must be dealt with differently in the draw mode?

Best regards,
Matthew

Answer (score 2):

Probably better to use a `label` for the node. The custom node types from `circuitikz` is intended to only generate the shape I believe, not include text.

Regarding why `node[ocirc,left]` didn't work, the error message you get gives a hint, in that it says `east` is not known. The `left` option sets `anchor=east`, but apparently the `ocirc` node doesn't define any anchor called `east`, and hence you get an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american, siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} \draw
(0,0) node[ocirc,label=left:Anode]{} to[short,i=$i'_D$] (1,0) to[empty diode, v=$v'_D$] 
(3,0) node[ocirc,label=right:Cathode]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption*{Figure: Diode}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```